# How to compare pixel colour with pixel by pixel using CGPoint in UIImage

Tags: objective-c, uiimage, wand

In my project I need to remove selected colour like wand tool.For this i was used flood fill algorithm([Flood fill](https://github.com/Chintan-Dave/UIImageScanlineFloodfill)).but it was not working properly for colour comparison(pixel by pixel).can any one suggest the solution.

In below images i need to remove background colour only(expected). 
[image]

output Result.

[image]

can any one please help me with code Or example.

Comment: The problem is that the "white" background is not actually pure white. Have you tried adjusting the `tolerance` parameter to account for this?

Comment: even I am getting a same issue i tried to adjust tolerance but complete image is getting erased.

Comment: Yes, I did that, I am not getting exact output which i excepted.Means expected colour pixels were still appearing.unexpected pixels were removed.

Comment: Can I use GPUImage for this.